# mp3 reading Error : file does not start with RIFF id

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, scipy, librosa

The error shows up when I try to read mp3 file 
via thinkdsp.read_wave()​
but with all .wav file, I used before was fine.

I really need to use this library because the whole codding was done.
So for avoiding future error, I need to fix only this code line. Or maybe closest as it could be.

```
from __future__ import print_function, division

import thinkdsp
import thinkplot
import pandas
import numpy

Raw_Wave_input=thinkdsp.read_wave('Skull_sound/inside-skull.mp3')
```

**Error Message**

```
--------------------------------------------------------
Error                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-33cbde5f990d> in <module>
----> 1 Raw_Wave_input=thinkdsp.read_wave('Skull_sound/inside-skull.mp3')

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thinkdsp.py in read_wave(filename)
     99     returns: Wave
    100     """
--> 101     fp = open_wave(filename, 'r')
    102 
    103     nchannels = fp.getnchannels()

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/wave.py in open(f, mode)
    508             mode = 'rb'
    509     if mode in ('r', 'rb'):
--> 510         return Wave_read(f)
    511     elif mode in ('w', 'wb'):
    512         return Wave_write(f)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/wave.py in __init__(self, f)
    162         # else, assume it is an open file object already
    163         try:
--> 164             self.initfp(f)
    165         except:
    166             if self._i_opened_the_file:

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/wave.py in initfp(self, file)
    129         self._file = Chunk(file, bigendian = 0)
    130         if self._file.getname() != b'RIFF':
--> 131             raise Error('file does not start with RIFF id')
    132         if self._file.read(4) != b'WAVE':
    133             raise Error('not a WAVE file')

Error: file does not start with RIFF id
```

Comment: If there is no method to read an .mp3 file, maybe try converting your .mp3 file to a .wav?

Comment: Why is this tagged with `librosa`?